# MVC html begin form return JavaScript Action result

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-5

in a view I have this code:

```
<div class="row">
    @Using (Html.BeginForm("myFn", "myCntl", FormMethod.Post))
        @<div>
            <input type="submit" value="Do" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
    End Using
</div>
```

And in the controllor this code:

```
Function myFn() As ActionResult
     Return JavaScript("alert('hello')")
End FUnction
```

I do not see the alert in the browser but it is printed in the window.
How can I make the code executable?

Answer (score 0):

`JavascriptResult` only works if you are calling it from AJAX. So you have to change your code to something like this.

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("myFn", "myCntl", new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod="POST" }))
{
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Do" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult myFn()
{
    return JavaScript("alert('hello')");
}
```

As a side note, there are way better ways to handle something like this through partial views or simple javascript on the client side. `JavascriptResult` is really a poor pattern.

Comment: I tried this: @Using (Ajax.BeginForm("myFn", "myCntl", new AjaxOptions())) but no luck

Comment: Make sure you have this package installed and included on your page https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax/3.2.2

Comment: I've edited my answer with working code. Convert that into VB and check again.